# Rails - Get the current url without the GET parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

request.url returns me this : http://localhost:3000/page?foo=bar.

Is there a method I can call to get http://localhost:3000/page , or do I have to parse the string to strip get parameters?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

`request.path` should return what you're looking for if you're not concerned about the hostname. Otherwise you might try:

```
url_for(:only_path => false, :overwrite_params=>nil)
```

Comment: I also ran into the recursive parameters problem, `/controller/action?param=1?param=2?param=3`, but the request.path worked excellent for me.

Comment: The problem with the above method is that if there are multiple paths for the same type of resource (say for a publication where some things are labeled "/news/post-name" and others "/blog-name/post-name"), then you could get the wrong path back.

Comment: @thekingoftruth That's true, but the highest priority route will be used, so be sure to order them correctly.

Comment: @tadman Good point. However, sometimes there is no priority between two routes--one model can be accessed from various urls depending on how they're tagged. (e.g. Movies section, TV section, Comedy section, etc.) In this case, url_for is not a viable solution. I will post the solution I found as a separate answer.

Comment: It's possible to parse the current URL with the `URI` module, rip off the queries, and re-emit that as an alternative.

Answer (score 18):

To get the request URL without any query parameters.

```
def current_url_without_parameters
  request.base_url + request.path
end
```

Answer (score 12):

I use the following:

```
request.original_url.split('?').first
```

It does not regenerate the path, and therefore gives you exactly the url that the end-user sees in their browser, minus query parameters.

Comment: Nice! Also the terser `request.url.split('?').first` worked for me.

Comment: @Franco I believe `request.url` is deprecated, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is more flexible, as it can work with `request.referrer` as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `full_url_for` - this omits any query params from the URL.

eg. for `http://example.com/foo?bar=1234` it returns `http://example.com/foo`

https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Http/URL/full_url_for/class