# request.fullpath with no parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

request.fullpath gives the fullpath plus any parameter passed, such as

```
/page?param1=value&param2&value
```

How can I get just the page with no params? Like

```
/page
```

Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947652/rails-get-the-current-url-without-the-get-parameters

Comment: I tried that but I can't get rid of the ? such as /page?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

### Use `path` instead of `fullpath`.

Although not documented, `request.path` worked for me. I usually use my plugin rails_web_console for playing with the request object.

**Update:**

As noticed by [turboladen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/172106/turboladen), "`[ActionDispatch::Request][2]` inherits from `[Rack::Request‌][3]​`, where `request.path` is defined".

`path` is not documented there, but the source displays script_name + path_info.

Answer (score 28):

what about a simple split:

```
request.fullpath.split("?")[0]
```

Comment: the source for #fullpath shows that it is a concatenation of #path and #query.  Save some work by just using #path http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request:fullpath (I understand this has been asked and answered, but it is still worth noting for future SO'ers)

Comment: Just because an answer works, doesn't mean: it's the correct answer. The upvotes are an example of lacking conscientiousness.

Answer (score 9):

no need for splitting,

`request.path_info`

gives you just that

Answer (score 3):

regular expression

```
request.fullpath.gsub( /\?.*/, "" )
```