# Rails/javascript: passing params values in URL redirects

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, redirect, conditional-statements

Redirects, in our case with geolocated IP address to get taxes right. The following works fine for urls without any params. Makes sure people in Spain land on the Spain payment page, and everybody else on the UK payment page.

```
<% if URI(request.original_url).path == '/subscriptions/spain' %>
  if (x.country.iso_code !== "ES"){window.location.replace('/subscriptions/new');}
<% elsif URI(request.original_url).path == '/subscriptions/new' %>
  if (x.country.iso_code == "ES"){window.location.replace('/subscriptions/spain');}

[…etc. etc.…]

<% end %>
```

But how do I do the same thing with params? How do I redirect, say

```
subscriptions/new?c=tree
```

to

```
subscriptions/spain?c=tree
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does this question's answer help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947652/rails-get-the-current-url-without-the-get-parameters

Comment: Not really, I looked at that, but thanks.

Comment: Can I ask how your question differs, so we can understand what does and doesn't apply?